# Stream with ffmpeg over LAN?

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to stream a mpegts file over LAN, with the command

```
ffmpeg -re -i in.ts -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts "udp://localhost:5000/live/stream"
```

And trying to capture 10s chunks of it over LAN(at server) at

```
ffmpeg  -i udp://192.168.xx.xx:5000/live/stream -c copy -f segment -segment_time 10 -strftime 1 "in /%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4"
```

This isn't working. I tested the stream in VLC, and there's nothing to play.

Now, I suspect this is a port issue, since FFMPEG doesnt seem to write/listen over the 5000 port specified. I used netstat to check, and there are no PID including ffmpeg on the port. However, the command

```
ffmpeg  -i udp://127.0.0.1:5000/live/stream -c copy -f segment -segment_time 10 -strftime 1 "in/%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4"
```

generates the desired output on my machine(localhost), as does ffplay. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While using UDP, you have to specify the IP of the server you are streaming to, not the IP of the server you are streaming from.

Streaming command

```
ffmpeg -re -i in.ts -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts "udp://192.168.target.IP:5000/live/stream"
```

Capture command

```
ffmpeg  -i udp://192.168.target.IP:5000/live/stream -c copy -f segment -segment_time 10 -strftime 1 "in/%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4"
```

Comment: That freaking perfect just single line `While using UDP, you have to specify the IP of the server you are streaming to, not the IP of the server you are streaming from.` this line should be in FFMPEG wiki.